# csrf and anti forgery token in MVC 2, dont want to validate ajax post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, csrf

I want to use the ValidateAntiForgeryToken but... I want to use it only on actions
that i do a regular post to. and not ajax with json. because regularly an attacker would be stopped by the cross domain restriction. my question is so:

if i have an action which i know i only call with posting JSON in AJAX and in which case the antiforgerytoken doesn't work , so i want to make sure the request is really an ajax request which means its really from my site , how can i do that in ASP.Net MVC 2?

so my general idea is to: put the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute on all actions with regular post. and to validate that a post is really an ajax post in all other acitons

so how can I make sure that a post to an action is really AJAX and not just a regular post?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write your own ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.

I would just take the source of the existing attribute and copy it into your won class then modify it so that OnAuthorization method checks the "filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest" and only performs the CSRF validation if that is false.

You also can easily attach the CSRF token to your AJAX requests, which I would say would be the better solution to your problem